# How to set/change value while onCreate under TabLayout first Tab

Tags: android

i have try a lot of example or tutorial on tablayout, all work fine 
(https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/, http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-fragment-tabs-in-android/)
but now i encounter 1 problem, which is i dont know how to set/change the TextView/ImageView while onCreate/onLoad

so far, what i able to do is, write all my code under onTabSelected, but this is not my solution because i cant show empty or static values on the 1st tab, then have to wait until click or slide again then only load the real data.

i'm sure it have a way or solution for my problem, can anyone share it to me (code/website)

or in order to have this Tab feature with viewpager contain recyclerview, Tablayout is not the right way to code, perhaps it have another more correct way to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do these changes inside of onCreateView of fragment that you want

Example:

```
  //Our class extending fragment
  public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

//Overriden method onCreateView
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    //Change R.layout.tab1 in you classes 
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.you_textview_id);
    textView .setText("Your text to show");
    //Returning the layout file after inflating
    return view;

 }
}
```

The TextView need to be previous declared in tab.xml that you're inflating, in our example, tab1.

Comment: thanks Ruann, it work :)
so if i have a recycleview, all related code also write inside my tab1.java? and can tab1 here make changes/update on the parents textview object also? any sample? thanks

Comment: @JiiN Wee That depends what you want. onCreateView will be called at creation of the Tab, you can manipulate your recycleview from tab or "parent.java ". To get parent from fragment use 'getActivity().findViewById(R.id.your_parent_text);' and then update

Comment: thanks again, Ruann, i will try it, but what u mean by the last word... then update? sorry i'm new with android

Comment: Do update/changes on the parents views that you want